# group by on the multiple inner join in postgres

Tags: sql

i have 3 tables the first table "A" is the master table

```
id_grp|group_name    |created_on             |status|
------+--------------+-----------------------+------+
    17|Teller        |2022-09-09 16:00:44.842|     1|
    18|Combined Group|2022-09-09 10:16:42.473|     1|
    16|admnistrator  |2022-09-08 10:11:14.313|     1|
```

Then i have another table table "b"

```
id_config|id_grp|id_utilis|
---------+------+---------+
      159|    16|        1|
      161|    16|       54|
      164|    17|       55|
      438|    17|       88|
      166|    18|       39|
      167|    18|       20|
      439|    16|       89|
      198|    18|       51|
```

Then i have the last table "C"

```
id_config|id_grp|id_pol|
---------+------+------+
       46|    16|     7|
       48|    17|     8|
       51|    18|     8|
       52|    18|     7|
       84|    18|     9|
      113|    17|     9|
```

but when i using group by with multiple join as follows

```
SELECT 
a.id_grp, 
a.group_name, 
a.created_on, 
a.status, 
count(b.id_utilis) AS users,
count(c.id_pol) AS policy
FROM a
inner JOIN b on a.id_grp =  b.id_grp 
inner JOIN c on a.id_grp =  c.id_grp 
GROUP BY   a.id_grp, a.group_name, a.created_on, a.status,
```

but i am getting wront result there both the count are creating matrix and multiplying each other

```
id_grp|group_name    |created_on             |status|users|policy|
------+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+------+
    17|Teller        |2022-09-09 16:00:44.842|     1|   10|    10|
    16|admnistrator  |2022-09-08 10:11:14.313|     1|    3|     3|
    18|Combined Group|2022-09-09 10:16:42.473|     1|   18|    18|
```

Comment: is it not a question for database

Comment: Aggregate in subquery then join.

Comment: I have removed the conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: @Akina is right.  You have no relationship between tables B & C so you get all combinations of each.  Count what you need in B, then in C, then join those temp queries to table A.

Comment: What would be the desired output you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: Yes, that how the cross product of multiple tables works in relational algebra. If you want separate cross products, then run two separate cross joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from   a 
join  (select   id_grp, count(*) as users  from b group by id_grp) b using(id_grp)
join  (select   id_grp, count(*) as policy from c group by id_grp) c using(id_grp)
```

| id_grp | group_name | created_on | status | users | policy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | Teller | 2022-09-09 16:00:44 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 18 | Combined Group | 2022-09-09 10:16:42 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 16 | admnistrator | 2022-09-08 10:11:14 | 1 | 3 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EttTNpPs)